# Symfony 4 - Setting up Braintree Payments integration

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, braintree

I am trying to set up Braintree integration in my Symfony 4 PHP app.

I have used composer to require and install the latest version of Braintree SDK, and have added testing credentials to env file.

**Set Up Client**

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v3

I then added the client code to my twig template for Drop-in UI.

```
<div id="dropin-container"></div>
<button id="submit-button">Request payment method</button>
<script>
 var button = document.querySelector('#submit-button');

 braintree.dropin.create({
  authorization: 'CLIENT_TOKEN_FROM_SERVER',
  container: '#dropin-container'
 }, function (createErr, instance) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
   instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
     // Submit payload.nonce to your server
   });
  });
 });
</script>
```

And included this script in the js block

```
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.14.1/js/dropin.min.js"></script>
```

**Set Up Server**

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/php

Next step is to generate a client token

```
$clientToken = $gateway->clientToken()->generate([
    "customerId" => $aCustomerId
]);
```

and then send token to client etc.

**Question**

My question is where do I put the server side code in my Symfony 4 app?

Do you create a Braintree.php service in src/Services and put all the Braintree PHP code in there or in the controller, or some in both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to keep Controllers as thin as possible. Controller method should:

- accept the request
- call the appropriate service
- handle response

This is all a controller should be responsible of. In your case, the appropriate service would be your `BraintreeService`, a class responsible for whatever you need to do with Braintree SDK or anything related to Braintree.

> Symfony follows the philosophy of "thin controllers and fat models". This means that controllers should hold just the thin layer of glue-code needed to coordinate the different parts of the application.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html